# How to call a Web Service from another WCF to return a data contract containing and object as data member

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-client

```
/* SERVICE CONTRACT */
[ServiceContract]
public interface IEntity
{
[OperationContract]
CustomerDetail GetCustomer(string entityID);
//string GetCustomer(string entityID);
[OperationContract]
List<CustomerDetail> GetCustomerList(List<string> entityIDList);
}

/* DATA CONTRACT */
[DataContract]
public class CustomerDetail
{
[DataMember]
public Customer customerDetail; //Customer is defined in the webservice i'm calling
}

/* Actual service contract implementation */
public CustomerDetail GetCustomer(string ID)
{
ThirdParty tpws = new ThirdParty();
var c = tpws.GetCustomerByCustomerID(ID);
CustomerDetail cd = new CustomerDetail();
999         cd.customerDetail = c[0];
return cd;
}
```

When I run this in VS2010 with breakpoint at line labelled 999 above, everything works well but the return fails to show anything in WCF Test Client - returning and error - **An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to ...**

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, but stop in the debugger before line "999" and look at what's in `c`. I bet that `c.Length == 0`.

Comment: In the post I said it worked well up to line 999 - meaning I checked the content of c[0] using QuickView and it had data in it exactly as expected but the return to WCT Test Client comes up wit an error - not sure may be data too big?!?!?!

Comment: You didn't specify what you meant by "it worked". Many developers writing that same sentence would have meant, "I single-stepped and there was no exception thrown" until line 999.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong info - I single-stepped and there was no exception until AFTER line 999. i.e. return cd; (return to client fails with error - An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to ...)

Comment: An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/MyWebService/Service1/entity. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that type 'Customer' is serializable (is it decorated with the DataContractAttribute, SerializableAttribute, or similar)?

Comment: I believe 'Customer' is serializable because at line labelled 999, c[0] has data and I believe this can only be if the web service call to tpws.GetCustomerByCustomerID(ID) returns a serialised data - correct me if my assumption is wrong.

Comment: Just because the Customer class was serialized by the web service that you received the object from doesn't necessarily mean that your application has the object defined as serializable (Unless of course both web services share a common assembly which defines the class).

Comment: Please how then should I make Customer serializable in my assembly?

Comment: Can you provide the Customer class for review?

Comment: I do not have the Customer class - Only have access to it via web service reference - object browser

Comment: On second thought... is the error occurring on the client or server side? I'm wondering if the response is malformed based on the error you are receiving. You can download Fiddler to help you see what the response sent from the server looks like.

Comment: I'm really glad you trying to help. I believe the error is at the client end my reason is because while debuging, line labelled 9999 using quick view shows that c[0] (which is a customer object) has the data I'm expecting. The error is show when the line containing 'return cd' is executed - I feel it may have to do with WCF Test Client not able to handle the data.

Comment: Check your WSDL/XSD to make sure that it includes the definition for the 'Customer' class. If it doesn't contain one then WCFTestClient won't be able to deserialize your response.

Comment: An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/MyWebService/Service1/…. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details

Comment: Did you verify that the Customer class definition is defined in the schemas listed in your WSDL?

Comment: Hi got it to work by editing the Resource.cs file in web reference and adding [DataContract] to Customer class declaration and also adding [DataMemeber] to each of the public properties. I guess with WCF serialization only works with [DataContract]/[DataMember]. My only concern is the Reference.cs file will be overwritten whenever I update the service reference.

Comment: That's great. One problem with the solution though is that if you have to regenerate your service reference because of updates to the service you WILL lose your changes.